# "System.InvalidOperationException" when calling WebService from external Webpage

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to implement a C# Soap WebService (I am the server side) which will be called from a webpage I don't own!I have some specification that I have to fulfill.

I created an interface which you can see here:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int connect();

    [OperationContract]
    int disconnect();

    [OperationContract]
    string login(string userName, string userPassword);
}
```

Another Interface call ICrossdomain. The specification says that it has to be reached under `http://InserNameHere:8080/crossdomain.xml.`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICrossdomain
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/crossdomain.xml")]
    Stream GetCrossDomain();
}
```

In the following you can see a part of the implementation:

```
public class MyService : IMyService, ICrossdomain
{
    public int connect()
    {
        log.LogInformation("Aufruf der Methode connect() Rückgabewert" + 0);
        DMSConnectResponseData crd = new DMSConnectResponseData(log);
        return crd.process();
    }
    public int disconnect()
    {
        log.LogInformation("Aufruf der Methode connect() Rückgabewert" + 0);
        DMSDisconnectResponseData drd = new DMSDisconnectResponseData(log);
        return drd.process();
    }

    public string login(string a_sDMSUserName, string a_sDMSUserPassword)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Aufruf der Methode login() mit den Parametern Username: "+a_sDMSUserName + " UserPassword " + a_sDMSUserPassword);
        DMSLoginReponseData lrd = new DMSLoginReponseData(log);

        String xml = lrd.process(a_sDMSUserName, a_sDMSUserPassword, SessionMap);
        return xml;
    }
```

An the implementation of my Service:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://InsertURLhere:8080");
string address = "http://InsertURLhere:8080/ServiceName";
ecatHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddress);
ecatHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), address);
ecatHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICrossdomain), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = ecatHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (smb == null)
{
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    ecatHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
}

ecatHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

ecatHost.Open();
```

On the webpage I have to read in the wsdl, specify the url (InsertURLhere:8080/ServiceName or without /ServiceName) and the URN (after read in the wsdl it will be set to BasicHttpBinding dont know what to insert there). After that I try to connect to the service, in Debug Mode it will jump into the constructor of the MyService Class and after that I just get the following message

> "Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.InvalidOperationException" in
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"

Anyone knows how to get a more specific Exception Message or in which direction I have to search to solve the problem, because to be honest I am very new to this topic!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: When the exception occurs, please check its StackTrace and include it in your post.

Comment: How to do when you cant debug to the place of the code where the exception occurs? Beginner question I think..